# How do these icons work: ✅️?

Tags: firefox, unicode

I can see these characters as colored icons:

```
✅️
```

It only works in Firefox for me. If you can't see the characters in color, it looks like this on my system (it's probably font-dependent):

[image: image description]

I can even see them in firebug and tab titles:

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

And [there's full file](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts-beta/emoji-ordering-rules.txt) of them. I also did this [document.title animation](http://darker.github.io/series.html) with them, which demonstrates that they work even outside HTML.

What is that?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52923/discussion-on-question-by-tomas-zato-how-do-these-icons-work-).

Comment: I'm using Opera and I definitely do not see them the way you have shown in the image "it looks like this". So, I'm tempted to edit that out of your question but it wouldn't be very substantial...

Comment: @StephanBijzitter: The fact that you and others don't see the icons that way is *why* the image is important. Don't remove it.

Comment: @user2357112 check the editor history. the way it was worded before was simply incorrect and misleading. after the edit it's fine now

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tITwM5GDIAI

Comment: I see them just fine on Chrome

Comment: @LeoWilson it depends on the OS. Chrome on Linux, Windows 8.1... doesn't display those colors

Comment: Keyword: OpenType-SVG (http://stateofwebtype.com/#OpenType-SVG, https://color.typekit.com/)

Comment: @Prinzhorn, [archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20171029030803/https://stateofwebtype.com/#OpenType-SVG) version.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

These characters are emojis that are recognized by the Unicode standards which defines what each character presents.

The exact look for them is different for each OS, and each application, but all depict the same thing.

The globe () is Unicode character `1F30F` and is [called](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f30f/index.htm) **EARTH GLOBE ASIA-AUSTRALIA**. the 2nd one (✅) is [called](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2705/index.htm) **WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK** and is Unicode 2705.

In that manner, there are thousands of emojis, some that every application supports and some with less support. See complete list here http://www.fileformat.info/info/emoji/browsertest.htm

Comment: The exact look for them depends on the font you use, because font are the things that define how a character should look and emojis are just characters.

Comment: Actually, the second one is (as you said) **WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK** combined with [VARIATION SELECTOR-16](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe0f/index.htm). ✅️ copied from the question looks like a white checkmark in a green box, ✅ copied from your answer looks like a white checkmark with a black border, and when I paste the variation selector after your ✅ white checkmark with a black border, I get the same ✅️ white checkmark in a green box. [**Screenshot of this comment for clarity**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veXqS.png)

Comment: They might not have noticed due to poor font support. On my browser, the green backdrop doesn't show up.

Comment: @Stijn, for me in Chrome both of them are the green-boxed checkmark http://i.imgur.com/Cv5RTFM.png

Comment: Oh, that's odd. I'm using Firefox.

Comment: @Stijn I'm using Firefox too and I see them fine (on the answer without green, on your comment with, without, without and with, in the question with).

Comment: the question is not about Unicode or not. It's about color in Firefox and monochrome in other applications

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc  but "other applications" are also not all the same. As said, Chrome shows it colored as well, Microsoft Word by default uses the Souge Emoji font for these and it's also colored, Stack Exchange Android app also shows the globe full colored.

Comment: It depends. Word 2016, IE and other applications on my PC shows that as monochrome except Firefox. Android uses a different technique for colorized fonts instead of layered fonts like Windows 8 and up.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Word 2016 on Windows 10 displays it nicely colored

Comment: My personal Windows 10 displays it with color but Windows 10 Enterprise at work doesn't. There's no font called Souge Emoji in either cases. On Linux Firefox is the only one to display in color. That means Firefox uses its own renderer like aitap said. In Windows 10 it's colored sometimes and monochrome sometimes

Comment: @Stijn Looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj7vI.png) for me in Firefox. For some reason, my green background is a a circle for me.

Comment: For yet another variation: this is Firefox on OS X: http://imgur.com/a/3j5ou

Comment: @Stijn They're all white with black border for me using Chrome [56.0.2924.87] on Windows 8.1 Pro. http://imgur.com/L7p8Dkp

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about *how* it's being rendered in Firefox, not *why* the emoji are there.

Comment: @totymedli Technically true, but to be fully technically accurate the exact look also depends on the fallback font the system uses if the current font doesn't have the emoji codepoints.  More practically, however, very very few fonts implement the emoji codepoints— 99% of the time you see emoji characters, you're looking at the OS's default emoji font.  **So “The exact look for them is different for each OS” isn't technically correct, but rather a _for-all-practical-purposes-accurate_ assessment of present-day emoji rendering.**

Comment: Of course it answers the question "how they work". They are defined in the Unicode standard and part of the font. How they are *rendered* is a different question, as they get rendered like any other glyph supported by the font, e.g. "a" or "+".

Comment: Agree with @SlippD.Thompson. The headings on Superuser.com use Arial font, however, the four emojis are rendered using Segoe UI Emoji (Chrome and Firefox, Windows 10).

Answer (score 75):

Firefox is using a [special font](https://github.com/mozilla/emojione-colr) for these [emoji characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Unicode_blocks). It's employing a relatively new and otherwise rarely used feature of TrueType fonts: layered colour glyphs. Other than that (i.e. having a special font with pre-coloured glyphs) these icons are ordinary Unicode characters.

Windows has native support for these coloured fonts [only in versions 8.1 and onwards](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1231701), thus Firefox installs EmojiOne privately and uses its own font renderer for it in Windows 7. This also explains the absence of colourful emoji icons in most other applications.

Comment: If there's native support for layered colour glyphs in Win10, why do they still show up in monochrome in, for instance, Edge?

Comment: @Bas, as we can see via Edge developer tools, Segoe UI Emoji doesn't get selected to display this page (other monochrome fonts do). Inserting the font to the font-family attribute does the trick: http://i.imgur.com/IXiNC86.png

Comment: @Bas Colored emoji support is in the latest Edge previews and will be in the next public version.

Comment: Curiously enough, Firefox on my Ubuntu 16.10 box displays black and white glyphs (I have booted into Win10 afterwards and confirmed they are indeed coloured)

Comment: @Luke Firefox on my opensuse displays colors exactly like the OP's image

Comment: @Luke Ubuntu has color glyph support planned for Unity 8.

Comment: Emojis requires encoding so encoding `UTF` and `UCS` standards will be helpful inorder to display special characters and emojis on a page

Answer (score 26):

**In short**: Firefox uses a [font](https://github.com/mozilla/emojione-colr) in which these symbols look the way they do.

These characters are a part of the Unicode Standard.

> Unicode is a computing industry standard for the consistent encoding, representation, and handling of text expressed in most of the world's writing systems. Developed in conjunction with the Universal Coded Character Set (UCS) standard and published as The Unicode Standard, the latest version of Unicode contains a repertoire of more than 128,000 characters covering 135 modern and historic scripts, as well as multiple symbol sets. -Wikipedia

Thus, unlike ASCII (which had very few), Unicode contains several symbol sets. Now while it has been standardized on what code should represent what alphabet or symbol, Unicode does not exactly specify how the symbol should look like. Thus, all operating systems have their own sets of symbol graphics to look different. This may include some being colored and some being just outlines or black and white.

Also, it is also possible for fonts to have their own set of art for these symbols so that the characters can go with the feel of the application. Even inside the application, you may have different pages using different sets of images. Thus, you can interact with the character like you would otherwise, but it would just look different.

You can see how exactly emoji (for , skip to #1483) look on various platforms [here](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

Comment: 128,000 is a *lot* of icons to draw. I don't blame the artists for going with black-and-white icons instead of full color.

Comment: @Dan, 128,000 is the number of characters, not symbols. These include language characters too, which are huge in number for languages like Japanese or Mandarin.

Comment: I don't understand your distinction. Aside from the very few non-renderable codes, don't the Japanese and Mandarin characters/symbols also have to be drawn by someone in order to be rendered? Sorry, I'm a bit naive about how Unicode works.

Comment: @Dan, I only meant that there are not 128,000 symbols that would have to be colored. Not saying there are not many to color, but that's nowhere close to 128,000.

Comment: Ah, I didn't mean to imply that they should all be colored, merely that drawing that many of *anything* is enough to make me not want to complicate (i.e. color) any of them. Haha.

Comment: @Dan no one draws that much code points, and almost no fonts contain characters for all Unicode code points. The font renderer will [substitute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_substitution) glyphs from another font when the current font doesn't contain those glyphs. [Why isn't there a font that contains all Unicode glyphs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34732718/995714)

Answer (score 2):

These characters "work" the same way as other characters, such as `a`, `ø`, `λ`, `ଶୁ`, `に` and `晨`, work.  Characters are represented by an abstract number, which is used to select and index an available font to display the character.

On your system, it appears that Firefox does its own rendering, and has access to fonts containing glyphs for, ,  and `✅️`.  Other applications will normally use the fonts made available by the X server (or equivalent), so be restricted to fonts you've installed or pointed your server at (e.g. with `xset +fp` or similar).

Multi-colour fonts are a recent and still fairly experimental development; traditionally, font glyphs are a single colour that can be composed against any background.

Answer (score 1):

Those are just Unicode characters so any textboxes that support Unicode can display them without problem, provided the font and glyphs are available on the system. However the *look and feel* for each Unicode character depends on the renderer and font used for them.

Traditionally characters are filled only with a single color. Colored emojis are quite a new thing, hence their support varies from platform to platform. [Various techniques have been invented for coloring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/color-fonts) like [embedded PNGs, SVGs or layered masks](https://typography.guru/journal/windows-color-fonts/). But all of them require a new renderer which was not available in older OSes.

As a result since version 50.0 Firefox has embedded its own renderer and font for supporting colored emoji. You can find it in the [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/50.0/releasenotes/)

> ## Changed
>
> Added a built-in Emoji set for operating systems without native Emoji fonts (Windows 8.0 and lower and Linux)

The font file can be found in `%FirefoxInstallDir%\fonts\EmojiOneMozilla.ttf`

### Update:

Firefox later switched to [Twemoji](https://github.com/mozilla/twemoji-colr/releases/tag/v0.3.1)